# Car Acceleration and Deceleration using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, accelerometer, sensors

Hello I'm trying to get the car acceleration and deceleration with flutter, Also I'm using the userAccelerometerEvent to deduct the gravity, however, I'm getting errors under event

1) I want to know how to measure the acceleration and deceleration using flutter. 
2) Why there is an error when I use userAccelerometerEvent

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
      if (event() >= 2 && event() < 5) {
        print('Between 2 and 5');
      }
      if (event() >= 10 ) {
        print('Greater Than 10');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What errors are you seeing?

Looks like you are using the `sensors` package from Flutter, the README is located here and describes how to listen to different sensor changes: [README](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/sensors/README.md)

Looking at your code, it looks like you are using the `event` parameter as a method `event()`. The `event` parameter is a `UserAccelerometerEvent` object with properties `x`, `y`, and `z`. You should access the x, y, and z values by doing: `event.x` or `event.y` or `event.z` instead.

The flutter team has some sample code for how to use the sensors package here: [Sample Code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/sensors/example/lib/main.dart)

Some relevant code from the example page below.

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _streamSubscriptions
        .add(userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _userAccelerometerValues = <double>[event.x, event.y, event.z];
      });
    }));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Yusef for your help, probably that's why I have the error, what I'm trying to do is to use the driver's smartphone to measure the acceleration and deceleration of the car, that's why I'm using the UserAccelerometer to measure since I don't want to constrain the driver to put the smartphone in a fixed position. I'm trying to understand how to differentiate between acceleration and deceleration.

Comment: @X2020 These events return the velocity of the device relative to the user. You can look at the value of `event.z`: a positive value means the device is moving towards the user, while a negative z value means the device is moving away (assuming the device is held upright and facing the user.)

You need to measure the change in velocity vs. the change in time in order to determine acceleration. You could store previous values of velocity along with timestamps in order to make this acceleration calculation. The value of `event.z` returns the velocity in m/s^2

Comment: Thank you so much Yusef Ouda, I'll try that :)